# Traversing a list of object

Tags: java, jpa

Code snippet:

```
public List<Rect> display(){
    TypedQuery<Rect> tp = em.createQuery("SELECT s,r FROM Rect r INNER JOIN r.cirlceId.squareCollection s", Rect.class);
    List<Rect> list = tp.getResultList();
return list;
}
```

inside my list is something like this

```
[0] Object[]
  [0] Square
  [1] Rect
[1] Object[]
  [0] Square
  [1] Rect
...
```

now how do you traverse the list to get square or Rect, or how do you return a list of Rect?

**Updated my question**

i'm a little new about JPQL query, what i want to achieve is something like this SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM Rect INNER JOIN Square WHERE Rect.squareId = Square.id
```

and insert the results in a list

Comment: You are returning List of Rect. So what is the question?

Comment: I assume that means that `Square` is a `Rect` and he wants to parse out `Rects` but I don't understand why a `Rect` is an `Object[]`. Going to need more information.

Comment: that is the problem, after invoking the create query, the `tp.getResultList()` returns a value of list of objects stated the tree above. From the list of objects, i want to get all Squares or all Rects

Comment: @galao: So what is the use of 'TypedQuery<Rect> ' declaration.  Should n't return only objects of Rect.class? instanceof will help, but I guess your problem is the list has objects other than Rect.class

Comment: i was trying to retrieve the Rect result, but it failed. even with just a List, it returns a list of object with Rect and Square inside.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an example on how you can do that. You can modify it as per your needs!

```
for(Object obj : yourList){
    if(obj instanceof Square){
       // Add to Square List
    }else if(obj instanceof Rect){
       // Add to Rect List
    }else{
       // Do what you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JPQL query has multiple select items. If you only need the `Rect`, change your query to `SELECT r FROM Rect r INNER JOIN r.cirlceId.squareCollection s` (remove the `s`). You might need to specify `SELECT DISTINCT r ...`. If your `squareCollection` is eagrly fetch, you can also get your squares from the object graph (i.e. get a `Rect` r from your result list and access r.circleId.squareCollection.get(0)...)

Comment: i'm a little new about JPQL query, but i what i want to achieve is something like this SQL Query `SELECT * FROM Rect INNER JOIN Square WHERE Rect.squareId = Square.id` i need each of the result to be in a list

Comment: Then you got that part right, the SQL query should be correct (you can skip the `INNER` keyword since your JPA provider will do that for you). That said, you can either have a `List<Rect>` following my answer or a `List<Object[]>` using your original post. In the first case, you can access `Square`s using the graph `r.circle.squareCollection.get(0)` or you can use R.J's approach to iterate your result list.

Comment: is there any way to combine the values of Square and Rect into 1 List?

Comment: The only way I can think of is inheritance. If both `Square` and `Rect` inherit from a super-class (say `Shape`) you could do that. Check [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Inheritance) out. Even so, you would end up with a `List<Shape>` and then use instanceof to distinguish the sub-type.